# Splitting Field of polynomial $x^{12}-1$ over $F_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the degree of the splitting field $[K:F_2]$ for the polynomial $x^{12}-1$ and I have already read often, that you need to find the smallest $r \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $F_{2^r}$ contains elements of order 12.

So the question really comes down to "What is the smallest $r$, s.t. $12|2^{r}-1$.

However, I don't really understand, how to get to this conclusion.

I found, that $1$ is a root of the polynomial; applied polynomial division and got a polynomial, which again had $1$ as a root and so on.

Finally I found, that $x^{12}-1 = (x+1)^4(x^8+x^2+1)$, the last factor being equal to $(1+x+x^2)^4$.

Adding a root $\alpha$  of $(1+x+x^2)$ (which is a field extension of degree 2 as this polynomial is irreducible); the second factor can be split up into two linear factors and therefore the whole polynomial should be a product of linear factors over the field $F_2(\alpha)$.

As there are many answers in this forum pointing towards the first solution, I wanted to ask, whether there is a good source which explains this answer. Furthermore, I can't seem to find the error in the second approach - what is the mistake there?

Comment: $x^{12}-1=(x^3-1)^4$ so you only need the splitting field of $(x-1)(x^2+x+1).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2^r-1$ is odd, there is no way for it to be a multiple of $12$. While the polynomial $f(X)=X^{12}-1$ has degree $12$, it does not have $12$ *distinct* roots in its splitting field. Indeed, as $f'(X)=0$, every root of $f$ is a multiple root. And as you found out (in a different way), $(X^3+1)^2=(X^6+1)$ and $(X^6+1)^2=X^{12}+1$ so that $$f(X)=(X^3+1)^4=(X+1)^4(X^2+X+1)^4,$$ i.e., we "really" want to find only the third roots of unity. The rule of thumb you started from holds only for *separable* extensions (i.e., when all roots are distinct)

Comment: Thanks! I already had a suspicion that there might be a requirement missing :) It's nice to see that the rule works with the third roots of unity - as r = 2 is the smallest natural number for which the relation 3|2^r -1 holds.